# Ajax запрос для запуска PHP скрипта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

В общем, у меня есть форма, я аяксом передаю данные с формы в файлик пхп и из него в бд, потом есть еще один файлик пхп который забирает данные из бд и формирует из них пдфку. Вопрос к умам, по клику на одну и ту же кнопку мне нужно выполнить оба действия, т.е должна произвестись и запись в бд и формирование пдфки, как мне это реализовать?

извините если вопрос тупой, и тд, я просто чуток поплавился из-за этих пдфок...

**UPDATE** Очевидно, что реализовать надо последовательно. Берёте первый файл, в конце подключаете к нему второй, и вуаля (спасибо и правда "вуаля" :) )

Comment: Нельзя сделать все в одном файле? Сразу с одной переменной и записать и составить PDF

Comment: Очевидно, что реализовать надо последовательно. Берёте первый файл, в конце подключаете к нему второй, и вуаля

Comment: Пожалуйста, киньте код и мы поможем..

Comment: После нажатия кнопки, браузер должен попросить сохранить pdf или отобразить в этом же экране?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете jQuery, то можно сделать примерно так:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'php_script1.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#your_form').serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php_script2.php',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
        alert('PDF generated!')
      }

    })
  }

})
```